# Javascriptのifをnullishかどうかで分岐する時の書き方

Tags: javascript

ある値がnullishかどうかで条件分岐をさせたい時があります。
今のところ以下のように書いているのですが、もっとすっきりした（具体的には、nullを2回書かなくても良いような）書き方があれば、ご教授願いたいです。

```js
if(a??null===null){
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a == null` (`===`ではなく`==`)はいかがでしょうか。可読性が良くないかもしれませんが。

Comment: 盲点でした！　==にもちゃんと使い方があったんですね。ありがとうございます！